# Can't access SVN on my CentOS home server

Tags: centos, svn

I've recently installed Subversion on my CentOS home server. I followed the instructions here:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion

but I can't access the repository from Eclipse (I've previously installed the subversion plugin for Eclipse and its working with no issues).

My subversion.conf which is in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ looks like this:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

#
# Example configuration to enable HTTP access for a directory
# containing Subversion repositories, "/var/www/svn".  Each repository
# must be both:
#
#   a) readable and writable by the 'apache' user, and
#
#   b) labelled with the 'httpd_sys_content_t' context if using
#   SELinux
#

#
# To create a new repository "http://localhost/repos/stuff" using
# this configuration, run as root:
#
#   # cd /var/www/svn
#   # svnadmin create stuff
#   # chown -R apache.apache stuff
#   # chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t stuff
#

<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos

   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      # SSLRequireSSL

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion repos"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
      Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

and then I restarted Apache.

But I get an error when trying to access the repository location from Eclipse or from http://xx.xx.xx.xx/repos in the browser.

Any help appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos` means "you **have** already created **repository** in `/var/www/svn/repos`", not in subdir of repos

Try to use repo from CLI svn-client (`svn ls URL`)- you'll get more useful error-message in case of problems